# Is it possible to create bidirectional relationships using only data annotations with EF Code First?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Using Entity Framework Code First and Entity Framework Migrations (4.3.0-beta1), I want to create a database structure like this:

[image: Database diagram]

If I define the model like this:

```
public class Country
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Capital")]
    public Guid? CapitalCityId { get; set; }

    public virtual City Capital { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid CountryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Capital")]
    public Guid? CapitalCityId { get; set; }

    public virtual City Capital { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid? StateId { get; set; }

    public virtual State State { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid CountryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<City>().HasOptional(c => c.State).WithMany(s => s.Cities);
        modelBuilder.Entity<City>().HasRequired(c => c.Country).WithMany(c => c.Cities);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And I add a migration, the following migration code is generated:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "Countries",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                CapitalCityId = c.Guid(),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .ForeignKey("Cities", t => t.CapitalCityId)
        .Index(t => t.CapitalCityId);

    CreateTable(
        "States",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                CountryId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                CapitalCityId = c.Guid(),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .ForeignKey("Countries", t => t.CountryId)
        .ForeignKey("Cities", t => t.CapitalCityId)
        .Index(t => t.CountryId)
        .Index(t => t.CapitalCityId);

    CreateTable(
        "Cities",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                StateId = c.Guid(),
                CountryId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .ForeignKey("States", t => t.StateId)
        .ForeignKey("Countries", t => t.CountryId)
        .Index(t => t.StateId)
        .Index(t => t.CountryId);

}
```

Wich results in the correct structure.

I want to know if it's possible to achieve this result without using the fluent API.

If I leave out the fluent API instructions, like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    //modelBuilder.Entity<City>().HasOptional(c => c.State).WithMany(s => s.Cities);
    //modelBuilder.Entity<City>().HasRequired(c => c.Country).WithMany(c => c.Cities);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Then two additional fields are created in the Cities table:

```
CreateTable(
    "Cities",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
            Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
            StateId = c.Guid(),
            CountryId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
            State_Id = c.Guid(),
            Country_Id = c.Guid(),
        })
...
```

But the fluent API instructions don't seem to be adding more information than could already be discovered using the Code First conventions.

I'd like to know if there is a better way to create this kind of relationship, especially one that doesn't require the fluent API.

The code snippets are available as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/1768915).